# Save Texture2D in .xnb format

Tags: c#, xna

I want to save a loaded Texture2D in .xnb format, how can i do it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Does that Work?

Hm, I don't think you can do that the way you want to.  The reason is that the XNB file is created outside of the game runtime.  The ContentManager is just a way of loading/deserializing this data. This can be seen in this diagram of the [XNA content pipeline's architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447745%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx).

[image: Diagram of the XNA Content Pipeline Architecture]

### So What Should You Do?

I'm guessing what you want to do is save out image information during the game and load it back in. To do that, you will need to write out the Texture2d information the same way you would save any other content in XNA.  There's great help with "[Saving Data to a Save Game file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx)" on MSDN, so I will not reiterate what they say so well.

In order to get the Texture data and write it back out, you'll want to use the pair of Texture2D methods called [Texture2D.SetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.setdata.aspx) and [Texture2D.GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.texture2d.getdata%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx).  I would probably just [use this overload that gets an array and sets an array of color information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197089%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx).

### Update Windows Only

App Hub has a [code sample for creating XNB files on Windows](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) that will let you do it if the computer has XNA Game Studio installed.

Comment: your suggestion is false. i want my user to add/remove pictures used in the game. Because the users could not produce xnb formats, i have to do it.

Comment: My statement wasn't false as it is *true*.  Also, I updated with a potential solution for Windows. IMO it falls short though as you need XNA Game Studio.

Comment: you're right now, the example you have given is true, sorry for misunderstanding !

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [ContentCompiler](http://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/) project hosted on Codeplex.  It will allow you to build images into `.xnb` format.

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about this project.